# RUN poetry install in Dockerfile does not generate poetry.lock

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, fastapi, python-poetry

I am trying to build a fastapi development environment using docker-compose.yml.

However, I am having trouble with the poetry.lock not being automatically generated when I run the poetry installation in the Dockerfile.

The pyproject.toml already exists.

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    container_name: "todo-backend"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "${BACKEND_PORT:-8000}:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always

  db:
    container_name: "todo-db"
    image: postgres:15.3
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT:-5432}:5432
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

volumes:
  db_data:
```

```
FROM python:3.11

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV TZ Asia/Tokyo
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /src

RUN pip install poetry

COPY pyproject.toml* poetry.lock* ./

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN if [ -f pyproject.toml ]; then poetry install --no-root; fi

ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "api.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--reload"]
```

Trying `$ docker compose run --entrypoint "poetry install --no-root" backend` in terminal works, but RUN in dockerfile does not work.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: The `poetry.lock` file shouldn't be generated; you should have a copy of it checked into source control, and it will tell the `RUN poetry install` Dockerfile line what exact package versions to install.  The Dockerfile will _never_ modify files on the host, even if you later run the image hiding its contents with a volume mount.  What behavior are you expecting to see?

Comment: I was expecting the installation of poetry defined in the dockerfile to be performed at build time and poetry.lock to be automatically generated based on the contents of pyproject.toml.

Comment: The purpose of the lockfile is to ensure the package versions you use in development are the same as in your final build artifact (a docker image in your case). If it generated during docker image creation, what would read and use the lock file?